# Python sixohsix twitter wrapper

Tags: python, twitter

i was looking at [sixohsix](https://github.com/sixohsix/twitter/blob/master/twitter/api.py) Twitter wrapper trying to understand the code and found out that for example:

```
t = Twitter(...)
t.statuses.home_timeline()
```

Theres no statuses or home_timeline methods or attributes in the Twitter class or TwitterCall, so clearly im missing some python magic in here. Could anyone explain me whats going on there?

thanks so much in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically `Twitter` is a subclass of `TwitterCall` and the magic takes place in `__getattr__`. If you're accessing an attribute that doesn't exist you'll get an `AttributeError`.

When that happens it runs `extend_call` with that attribute as argument and that'll call `self.callable_cls` (which also happens to be `TwitterCall`). This result in another `TwitterCall` object. The same trick is then repeated because it'll discover that `home_timeline` doesn't exist on that object either. It'll then call this object (because you're writing `home_timeline()`) and that makes a HTTP request to Twitter.

The easiest way is to step through the code to see what's going on. When you're accessing an attribute you need to read `__getattr__` and when you're making a method call you need to read `__call__`.

Answer (score 1):

There is, [line 141](https://github.com/sixohsix/twitter/blob/master/twitter/api.py#L141). You should read about [`__getattr__`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getattr__).

In your example, all attributes not defined for `TwitterCall` class (or its descendant `Twitter`), that is, if `AttributeError` is raised by `object.__getattr__`, are recursively translated to a call to Twitter API, with `uriparts` combining all the attributes in a tuple.

So in your example, a call to `statuses.home_timeline` uri will be made in the end of recursion.